# Rendering html in rails 3

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am using Rails 3.2.1 and ruby 2.1.5.

In one of my controller I need to render a HTML line where I will include a source for a javascript file.  much like the below code.

```
  def sample_application
     render :html => "<script type='text/javascript' src='http://js.live.net/v5.0/wl.js'></script>"
  end
```

I know the above syntax is horribly wrong.

what should I change above so that I can include the Javascript source by rendering.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
def sample_application
    respond_to do |format|
        format.js { render 'sample_application.js.erb' }
    end
end
```

and in sample_application.js.erb you can put `<script type='text/javascript' src='http://js.live.net/v5.0/wl.js'></script>`

Comment: hey! thanks for the reply. But! what is respond_to here? Also I don't have that Javascript file locally. it's present on the web. So, I can't mention the path to the file here.

Comment: one option is that you can create one sample_application.js.erb file

Comment: Actually I have one such file and it's working properly. but, my new test case needs to delete that file and render the Javascript within the controller